# Erlang butlast function

Tags: erlang

I'm trying to make a butlast function in Erlang that will return a list without the last element if you give it a list. This is what I have:

```
butlast([]) -> undefined;
butlast([H, _]) -> H;
butlast([H|T]) ->[H|butlast(T)].
```

However, my output looks like this:

```
butlast([1,2,3,4,5,6]).
[1,2,3,4|5]
```

Why is this happening? Isn't the pipe operator `|` supposed to cons the 4 and 5 together?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the 2nd case, you should return `[H]` instead of `H`:

```
-module(a).
-compile(export_all).

butlast([]) -> undefined;
butlast([H, _]) -> [H];
butlast([H|T]) ->[H|butlast(T)].
```

Test:

```
1> c(a).
{ok,a}
2> a:butlast([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]).
[1,2,3,4,5]
```

Comment: @Ccyan - you thank by up voting and selecting the checkmark, not by commenting.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson I already up voted and will accept answer as soon as it allows me. Just wanted to show gratitude.

Comment: this version doesn't work with a list of length 1, the second clause should be: `butlast([_]) -> [];`

Comment: What Pascal said and returning undefined is a bit un Erlangish.  I'd call erlang:error(badarg) for empty lists.  This is what the built in functions do in these cases.  But that's of course a matter of taste